# Can you use a Z-Test with a sample size of 1?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, feature-selection, statistical-power, categorical-encoding, z-test

## Background

I'm performing a feature selection process on a fraud dataset.

The dataset is made up of roughly 300 columns and 40,000 rows. It has a single binary indicator for a target.

A lot of the columns are constant or nearly constant (80%+ one value, 2-10 unique values). I've already removed the constant columns, but I'd like to remove most of the nearly constant columns too.

To do this, I'm [one-hot-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot) each column and then calculating the correlation between the dummy and target variables.

I'd like to remove all columns below a correlation of $X$, where $X$ is decided by a statistical test that is dependent on the percentage of 1s in the dummy and target columns.

## What I've done so far

I've created a function in Python that calculates an expected distribution if a variable is linked to the target column `x%` of the time. It gives me a distribution like this:

[image]

where x is the correlation level, and y is the binned number of times that correlation range occurs.

As you can see, this distribution is centred around a correlation of `0`, which is the expected mean when the link between the target and dummy variable column is `0%`. To produce this distribution, I created pairs of columns, with 1s randomly positioned in `y%` of the rows, and calculated their correlation. This is a sample of the true distribution of all columns with `y%` as 1s.

This function returns me the mean and the standard deviation of an expected distribution for a given link-percentage.

I'd like to use this distribution to calculate the statistical probability that the true correlation is above/ below (one-tailed test) the distribution's mean. For example, my null hypothesis, $H_0$, would be:

> The correlation between the dummy variable and the target column is $X$.

The alternative hypothesis, $H_A$, would be:

> The correlation between the dummy variable and the target column is $<X$.

## Question

I'm confused about what **statistical test** to use to calculate the probability. I feel like I have a reasonable estimate of the population mean and standard deviation through my sampling for the true distribution. That makes me think I should use the [Z-Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-test).

However, when I calculate the correlation between my dummy variable column and the target column, I have a sample of size 1, which lowers the power of the Z-Test. On the other hand, the standard deviation of my expected distribution is small; therefore, a difference should still be easy to pick out.

Given all of the above, is the Z-Test a good way to calculate the probability of a single value being lower than the expected mean?

Comment: The Z-test is a test for the mean. For correlation there are different tests, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient#Inference I don't by the way understand what you hope to achieve by the one-hot encoding, and neither do I understand why you think you have a sample size of 1.

Comment: This question is based on poor understanding on my part. Basically, I'm asking if I can use estimators for $\mu$ and $\sigma$ to calculate the likelihood of an observation being part of the same distribution. I think the answer is clearly yes, but I didn't know how to phrase that yesterday when I wrote the question.